# React customHook returns correct data after second call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem because whenever I try to return data from my custom useValidation hook it returns it correctly after second call.

For example here is my component that uses custom hook.

```
const { runValidation, errors } = useValidation();

return (<button onClick={runValidation}>Test</button>) // Returns {} on first click and finally {...data} on second
```

Then inside my useValidation hook I have state for errors:

```
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

const validate = () => {
    setErrors(data);
}

const runValidation = () => {
    validate();
  };

  return { runValidation, errors };
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by return ? I tested it and the state is correctly updated. What is the problem ?

Comment: I've quickly re-created the issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-grass-9flix When you click Test button for the first time it returns empty object. Therefore the validation thinks that there are no errors as the object is empty which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour.

Your problem is that you access the data directly after setting the state, that is before the component is updated. Therefore you'll only see the previous data.

Try to display the state in your component rather than logging it.
You'll see the state correctly updated.

```
const { runValidation, errors } = useValidation();

// will display the correct state after update
return (<button onClick={runValidation}>{errors.key}</button>);
```

```
const useValidation = () => {
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const validate = () => {
    setErrors({ key: 123 });
  };

  const runValidation = () => {
    validate();
    console.log(errors); // will log {} immediately after
  };

  return { runValidation, errors };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update the sate, react doesn't immediately update it. The value is passed into a queue and then updated on the next render. You are actually always printing the previous value, which you can't notice in your example, because the value is always the same.

When you call `setState` what react does is, it throws away your whole component and renders it again with the new value. You can't access the new value in the same step. Since you do the `console.log` in the same function/step with `setErrors`, it will show the previous value. This is because the component hasn't been updated with new values yet.

Comment: what is the solution for this? do i need to return data from component using useEffect or useCallback?

Comment: It really depends on your use case. Most of the time `useEffect` or similar hooks would be the right choice.